# How to create a downsampling on downsampled key in redis timeseries

Tags: redis, time-series, redistimeseries

Here is the use case:

I have metric called `count`
I am downsampling it by creating a rule to the key/downsampling rule `countPerMinute`

Now when I try and create another rule for hourlyAggregation(have a slightly complicated case) redis time series doesn't allow me to create a rule with the `countPerMinute` key as a source key for another rule.

As there are millions of keys and huge volume we have set only couple hours of retention period on raw data keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create a compaction rule where the source is a destination of another compaction rule.

```
TS.CREATE x1
TS.CREATE x2
TS.CREATE x3

TS.CREATERULE x1 x2 AGGREGATION sum 1000
TS.CREATERULE x2 x3 AGGREGATION sum 1000000    <----- error
```

Instead, you should create all compaction rules directly from the raw samples series:

```
TS.CREATERULE x1 x2 AGGREGATION sum 1000
TS.CREATERULE x1 x3 AGGREGATION sum 1000000
```

Some test code:

```
TS.ADD x1 123001 101
TS.ADD x1 123002 102
TS.ADD x1 123003 103
TS.ADD x1 200000000 2000

TS.RANGE x1 - +
TS.RANGE x2 - +
TS.RANGE x3 - +
```

Comment: @ Lior Kogan : I cannot keep raw data for more than couple of hours, so my daily compaction will lead to inaccurate results.

Comment: @sampopes I see your point. Indeed it makes much sense to create a compaction based on another compaction. We'll add this to our backlog.